# get process id in shell without saving to a temporary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

Hi linux/bash experts,

I would like a universal way to get the process id of the previously run process.

I know that I can do this:

```
# child_script
myprocess & pid=$! && echo $pid
```

However I want to pass the pid to another variable in a parent shell script.

```
# parent_script
myvar=$(bash child_script.sh)
```

This is all fine. But if myprocess runs for a long time, say a server process, then the subprocess command in the last one would hang (see e.g., [Bash background process still blocking script flow in subshell](https://superuser.com/questions/1080695/bash-background-process-still-blocking-script-flow-in-subshell/1080829)) Also I don't want to direct stderr/stdout of the long running process to /dev/null, since I want to monitor it.

So a hacky way is to save the pid in a temporary file

```
# child_script
myprocess & echo $! > /tmp/pid.txt
```

Then on the outside, I do

```
# parent_script
pid=$(cat /tmp/pid.txt)
```

But this is clearly hacky. Is there a way to avoid doing this? This is my only complaint about bash/shell after all these years using it. Thanks!

Comment: I think there's no definitive answer to this. I'd use environmental variables, but essentially that would be the same as keeping the PID in a plain text file.

Comment: @DmitryPonkin that's a nice idea!

Comment: @DmitryPonkin I don't get the idea. A child inherits environment from its parent, but it's a copy. The environments are then completely separated and you cannot modify the environment of one process from the other. It's possible for a parent to pass data to a child by setting environment variables *before* the child is created; but the child can never alter variables of the parent process (unless with a privileged debugger, but this is not the right thing). What is your idea exactly?